# Rails 3 + lazy loading + Kaminari for pagination + HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, haml, lazy-evaluation, kaminari

I would like to use the kaminari gem to paginate over search results. Since the gem does not "pollute" ActiveRecord::Base and Array, kaminari is actually my preferred way to go (from an architectural point of view). Unfortunately there is Rails 3 and its lazy loading concept that makes things a little bit confusing (at least at my scenario).

In my HAML-Template I would like to list all of my search results. When the result set is empty, I want to display a message telling the user that no results have been found. In the past I could do the following:

```
- unless @results.empty?
  ... search results ...
- else
  ... no results found ...

= paginate @results
```

Since .empty? does not force loading this does obviously no longer work in Rails 3. Jep, I could use .all in my Query to force loading. Unfortunately .all returns an Array and kaminari's paginate View helper does not work with Arrays (the right philosophy imho). I am curious how you would handle this kind of situation. Any best practices? All of my attempts ended in ugly constructions (like the one below). :/

To make things a little bit clearer:

My Controller action:

```
helper_method :keys

def groups
  @results = []

  if params[:query].present?
    @results = Group.public
                    .where({:body.matches_any => keys} | {:subject.matches_any => keys})
                    .order('groups.updated_at DESC')
                    .page(params[:page])
                    .per(1)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

My "ugly" HAML-Template:

```
%h1= "Search results for \"#{params[:query]}\""
%br
%ol
  - @results.each do |group|
    %li
      = link_to group.subject, group
      %br
      = group.body
      %br
      = group.created_at

- if @results.empty?
  %div No results found ...
- else
  =paginate(@results)
```

The problem here: it creates an ol-tag although no results have been found.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

works for me:

```
- if @applications.present?
  %ul
    - @applications.each do |application|
      %li= application.name
  %p= paginate @applications
- else
  %p No results found ...
```

with **kaminari (0.12.3)**